# Using custom rule in Jena to assign individual to type

Tags: java, rdf, jena, jena-rules

Is it possible to add a rule in Jena which defines the type of an individual?

For example

```
String r;
r = "[rule1: (?a example:drives ?b), (?b rdf:type example:Truck) -> 
        (?a rdf:type example:TruckDriver)]";
//then parse and send to reasoner...etc
```

All of the examples and documentation I found online uses custom rules to assign relationships between individuals (object properties) as opposed to this rule which is used to assign an individual to a class.

Comment: Yes, it is.  This looks like one, in fact.  Are you have some particular problem with it?  Is it not producing results that you're expecting, or something?

Comment: I tried creating a rule similar to this and using the Jena reasoner to  add an individual which would drive a truck to the class of truck drivers.  After creating an inferred model the individual does not show when I call for a list of members of the TruckDriver class.  I wanted to know if perhaps there was something wrong with my rule syntax as no errors are generated upon compiling.

Comment: Specifically, I wanted to ensure it was possible to assign types in rules, because every example I have found throughout Jena tutorials uses custom rules to assign relationships and not individuals to classes.

Comment: It is legal, and there are examples in the documentation (but whether you encountered them would depend on which tutorials, etc., you were using).  I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> All of the examples and documentation I found online uses custom rules to assign relationships between individuals (object properties) as opposed to this rule which is used to assign an individual to a class.

Actually, the documentation [Reasoners and rule engines: Jena inference support](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#rules) gives examples of some rules that introduce triples whose property is `rdf:type`.  E.g. (from that document), there's a rule for RDFS reasoning that says, "when `?x` is related to `?y` by a property `?p` with domain `?c`, then `?X` has type `?c`:"

> [rdfs2:  (?x ?p ?y), (?p rdfs:domain ?c) -> (?x rdf:type ?c)]

In that same example block, there two more rules whose heads have triples using `rdf:type`:

> [rdfs3:  (?x ?p ?y), (?p rdfs:range ?c) -> (?y rdf:type ?c)]
>   [rdfs9: (?x rdfs:subClassOf ?y), (?a rdf:type ?x) -> (?a rdf:type ?y)]